# set theory - Image of set under function is a set

Tags: set-theory

I'm learning about classes and sets.
 how can I prove that the image of set under function is a set?

what I have to show is as follows.

> "let $f: A\to B$ be a function and A be a set.$\quad$is there any class C such that $f(A)\in C$?"

at first glance, I tried to make a singleton $\{f(A)\}$  from the axiom of pair.
however, axiom of pair guarantees that there is a pair $(a,b)$ if $a,b$ are set or element. and same problem for axiom of class formation.

I feel like the assumption : 'A is a set' is curcial... but I can't go any further.

Comment: Can the axiom of specification be used to specify the set as the subset of B corresponding to the image of f?

Comment: oh, I didn't know that axiom. thanks. it fits exactly.

Comment: why my textbook doesn't introduce such an important axiom? it's on set theory, informs difference of class and set, but no axiom of specification.. i can't understand..

Comment: @Thomas: Why is $B$ a set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila hmm...axiom of not reading the question carefully?

Comment: For a start, what is your set-theoretic def'n of "function"?.

Comment: It's defined by relation. relation R is subclass of $A \times B $ such that "for every element A, there is one and only one pair having 'a' as the first coordinate" then R is called 'graph of function' and blah blah

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$ in your formulation? Sets? Classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a function as a certain kind of $f\subset A\times B$ then an instance of the Axiom Schema of Comprehension (which has other names) declares the existence of $\{b\in B:\exists a\in A\;((a,b)\in f)\},$ which is of course what we mean by $f(A).$

The idea is that,given any set $B$ and any stated property we have the set of just those members of $B$ with that property. This replaces an early idea, which I have seen referred to as the Axiom of Abstraction, in which it was supposed that we could have the set of all things that have any given property. This was busted by Russell's Paradox.